# IIS Default Website Not Starting

Tags: iis, iis-8

I'm trying to start the default website of IIS 8 on Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials and I get a message with the error, "This website cannot be started. Another website may be using the same port."
The ports the website is trying to use is 80 and 443.
The other ports being used are 65520 and 65500.
When I look up the service which is using the port in Netstat (Command Prompt), it comes up with PID 4. In the task manager, it says that "SYSTEM" is using it. I can't end SYSTEM.

What's wrong?